# "All these expenses are incurred by me" or "for me"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, determiners

Context: We went to tour for official purpose. We to submit actual bills to office for reimbursement. We filed all the bills and have to written on top of that to notify that these expenses belongs to three of us.

> Theses expenses are incurred by me and Mr.A

OR

> These expenses are incurred for me and Mr. A

Which one is the correct usage?

Answer (score 1):

Both *for* and *by* may be appropriate in different senses. For instance:

- **For** designates the beneficiary. If Mr. A paid the restaurant tabs and Mr. B paid the taxis and you paid the hotel bill, each of you has incurred expenses **for** all three of you.
- **By** designates the payer. You may claim reimbursement only for the expenses actually incurred **by** you—the money which you yourself laid out, or the charges which appear on your credit card statement.

  > These expenses were incurred by me for me, Mr. A and Mr. B.

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely want to use "incurred by" in this instance. "Incurred for" doesn't make sense. While the meaning is not exactly the same, think of the word "incurred" as meaning "used." You would not say "these things were used **for** me," but "used **by** me."